# Is it possible to get gender ratio on Facebook page which does not belong to me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, data-analysis, bigdata

I have read the Facebook API document and it seems we can only use the Graph API for our own Facebook Page.

I would like to do some gender research and is it possible to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get gender insights for Pages you own, you need a Page Token with `manage_pages` and `read_insights`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/

Comment: Yes, so there is no way to get gender ratio for the other one's page.:(

Comment: no, of course not. it would also be weird to get google analytics data of pages you don´t own ;)